# if else array lookup

Tags: javascript, if-statement, contacts

I have an array of contacts like this:

```
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "likes": "beer",
}, // other contacts
```

and a function for lookups using `if/else` that is called like:

```
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

If function finds both parameter with name `"Akira"` and a property `"likes"`, it will return `"beer"`. If it can't find such name it should return `"no such name"`   , and if it can't find parameter "likes" it will return `"no such property"`.

I would be glad to see your suggestion on how to better write it , but fixing my code would be superb too.  ( it returns `"undefined"` instead of `"no such contact"`)

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

    var name = contacts[i].firstName;
    var propz = contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop);

    if (name == firstName && propz) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (propz !== prop && firstName == name) {
      return "no such property";
    } else if (firstName !== name && propz == prop) {
      return "no such contact";
    }
  }
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "lastName");
```

Thanks!

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean but you are comparing it to the passed in string

Comment: Open-ended code review questions aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow. I recommend migrating this to [Codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mistake you are making is that [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) returns a boolean but you are comparing it to the passed in string. Additionally, if you are returning from every `if/else` block, there's really no need for the `else/if` , you can just have `if`:

Here's how you can think of your cases:

```
// store current contact in a variable
var contact = contacts[i];

// get properties from the current contact
var name = contact.firstName;
var propValue = contact[prop];

// check for existence of the passed in first name and property
var hasName = name === firstName;
var hasProp = contact.hasOwnProperty(prop);

// if it has both, return property
if (hasName && hasProp) {
  return propValue;
}

// if it only has the name, return 'no such prop'
if (hasName) {
  return 'no such prop';
}

// otherwise it has neither so we return 'no such contact'
return 'no such contact';
```

#### Demo

```js
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "likes": "beer",
}];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    // store current contact in a variable
    var contact = contacts[i];

    // get properties from the current contact
    var name = contact.firstName;
    var propValue = contact[prop];

    // check for existence of the passed in first name and property
    var hasName = name === firstName;
    var hasProp = contact.hasOwnProperty(prop);

    // if it has both, return property
    if (hasName && hasProp) {
      return propValue;
    }

    // if it only has the name, return 'no such prop'
    if (hasName) {
      return 'no such prop';
    }

    // otherwise it has neither so we return 'no such contact'
    return 'no such contact';
  }
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes")); // beer
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "something else")); // no such prop
console.log(lookUpProfile("Someone else", "likes")); // no such contact
```

---

Alternatively, instead of a loop you can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the person by their first name and then return based on the results of `find()`:

```
// finds the person with the provided name or return undefined
var contact = contacts.find(function(c) {
  return c.firstName === firstName;
});

// if no contact exists, return 'no such contact'
if (!contact) {
  return 'no such contact';
}

// if contact doesn't have the prop, return 'no such prop'
if (!contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  return 'no such prop';
}

// otherwise return the prop value
return contact[prop];
```

#### Demo

```js
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "likes": "beer",
}];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  // finds the person with the provided name or return undefined
  var contact = contacts.find(function(c) {
    return c.firstName === firstName;
  });

  // if no contact exists, return 'no such contact'
  if (!contact) {
    return 'no such contact';
  }

  // if contact doesn't have the prop, return 'no such prop'
  if (!contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    return 'no such prop';
  }

  // otherwise return the prop value
  return contact[prop];
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes")); // beer
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "something else")); // no such prop
console.log(lookUpProfile("Someone else", "likes")); // no such contact
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got the answer from nem035's post.

You may still see this snippet if you want to explore another way.

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) property to first filter the json object which matche with the first name. Then retrieve the value of the key which you are passing through `prop`.

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "likes": "beer",
    }]

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
var _toReturn =""
//_inArray will only have matched json object
var _inArray=contacts.filter(function(item){ 
  return item.firstName = firstName;
})
if(_inArray.length !==0){
console.log(_inArray[0])
  _toReturn =_inArray[0][''+prop+''];
}
// here you can also check if key prop exist in current object
else if(_inArray.length ==0) { 
_toReturn="no such contact";
}
return _toReturn;
}
document.write('<pre>'+lookUpProfile("Akira","likes")+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/xkr0cLud/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is never executing the whole for loop. On the first element of the loop all options return something.

Your function is trying to do too many things. It would be better and easier to work if you split the functionality in smaller functions.

I would first split the functionality of finding a contact:

```
function findContact(firstName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        var name = contacts[i].firstName;

        if(name === firstName) {
            return contacts[i];
        }
    }

    // contact was not found.
    return undefined;
}


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var contact = findContact(firstName);

    // undefined is a falsy value
    if(!contact) {
       return "no such contact";
    }

    // no need to else because the if branch terminates the function with a return
    var propz = contact.hasOwnProperty(prop);

    if(!propz) {
        return "no such property";
    }

    // again, no need to add an else
    return contact[prop];
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "lastName");
```

Then you can replace the findContact function code with a functional implementation using [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like:

```
function findContact(firstName) {
    return contacts.find(function(contact) {
       return contact.firstName === firstName;
    }
}
```

Or if your code will run on ES6 you can simplify a little more:

```
function findContact(firstName) {
    return contacts.find(contact => contact.firstName === firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rather prefer to use `for in` loop for array object. You should also return your result outside of loop .You can get object key by `Object.keys()`.

```
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "likes": "beer",
},
{
    "firstName":"Suu",
    "likes" : "computer"
}];
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  for (var i in contacts) {
    var name = contacts[i].firstName;
    var propz = Object.keys(contacts[i])[1];    
    if (name == firstName && propz == prop) {
      result = contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (prop != propz && firstName == name) {
       result = "no such property";
    } else if (firstName !== name && prop == propz) {
       result = "no such contact";
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(lookUpProfile("Suu","likes"));
```